# How do I check if an environment variable exists in Robot?

Tags: environment-variables, robotframework

`Variable Should Exist` does not work with environment variables, when I try it throws this error `Invalid variable syntax '%{ENV_VAR}'`.

Is there a way to check without assigning the value of the env_var to a local var and use the keyword above on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [OperatingSystem](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html) library has a keyword named [Environment Variable Should Be Set](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Environment%20Variable%20Should%20Be%20Set) which can be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

you could use combination of `Run Keyword And Return Status` and `Get Environment Variable`:

```
${status}    Run Keyword And Return Status    Get Environment Variable    BUILD_NUMBER
```